# How do I get the output to produce random numbers?

Tags: java, random

This is what I have so far

```
    import java.util.Arrays;

public class Randoms {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] array = new int [50];
        for (int index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
            int j = (int) Math.random() * 101 + 1;

            System.out.println(j);
        }

    }

}
```

My output just produces a bunch of 1s. I want numbers from 0-100? Any help would be appreciated. I am fairly new to Java so sorry if this is a really dumb mistake. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's because you are casting to integer. You are casting in the wrong place

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you `type-cast` it to `int` it will round down to 0. Because it first calculates the `(int) Math.random()`

try the following code :

```
 for (int index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
           array[index] =  (int)(Math.random() * 100);
            System.out.println(array[index]);
        }
```

Comment: Now I'm getting all zeros. Maybe it's something with the array, I'm not too sure.

Comment: I thought you are just printing the value of `j` did you copy paste the above code?  I'm pretty sure you won't get all zeros.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the `java.util.Random` which would be something like:

```
Random random = new Random();
int yourRandomNumber = random.nextInt(100);
```

This will print out a random number between 0 and 100. You can read about `Random` [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt()). If you want a number between 1 - 100 you would do:

```
Random random = new Random();
int yourRandomNumber = random.nextInt(99)+1
```

If you want a bunch of random numbers, you can do:

```
    Random random = new Random();
    int[] array = new int [50];
    for (int index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
        int yourRandomNumber = random.nextInt(99)+1
        System.out.println(yourRandomNumber);
    }
```

If you are set on using `Math.random` you would do:

```
int yourRandom =  Min + (int)(Math.random() * ((Max - Min) + 1))
```

Comment: @Rodbrollin You're welcome. Which did you use? Also, feel free to upvote/accept.